# Revit Api: Can not edit joined walls LocationCurve

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I have a Revit model that contains a series of wall joined together and I want to edit their location. After trying the solution here

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/08/edit-wall-length.html

it happens that I can only apply the modification to a single wall element but not a group of walls joined together. I always receive the error message that my walls (right after I commit my modification) can not be joined, and all the walls can not be re-created except the last one from my modified wall list.

If I modify them all then commit the change instead of commit right after each modification, all of the wall are reported can not be re-created.

I suspect that the walls are un-joined and/or overlapped after the change, but that is not possible from my modification data and my debug info.

What is the cause of the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unjoin a wall by setting its [`LocationCurve` `JoinType` property](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/00b7a1a8-0e12-d02e-7e25-4716baf6dcdc.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have managed to figured out the problem is that when I modify the location curve, the joins at either of the wall segments do not match. This can be solved by unjoin them before and re-join them after modification. 2 new things arise:

1. which is better: WallUtils.AllowWallJoinAtEnd() or LocationCurve.JoinType ?

Comment: 2. I have read somewhere on this site that says I should be careful with LocationCurve because sometimes it is the center line of the wall, sometime it is the edge line of the wall. Is there anything I should take note about this? Does it have anything to do with the "Location Line" constraint in wall instance property in Revit project? What is the default value/ behavior? Thank you master.

Comment: I would prefer `WallUtils`, since it is higher level with dedicated behaviour.

Comment: The wall location line is always the centre line of the wall, cf. The Building Coder discussion of the [Wall Compound Layers](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/11/wall-compound-layers.html).